# Cannot find class assert symbol during maven build of an existing java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have converted my existing Java project to Maven.
I don't know much about Maven. Can someone please help me out?

These are the dependencies I used in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>    
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the error I got:

```
[ERROR]/C:/Users/SS078451/eclipseworkspace/Employee_detailsdemo/src/Employee_detailsdemo/DataExtractionTest.java:[2,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  symbol:   class Assert
[ERROR] location: package org.junit
```